# two string replacement at the same time

Tags: python

I want to replace chars in a string, but it must all happen at the same time.
I don't want one replacement to affect the second.

For example, I have the string "hello world". I want to replace h with e and e with h. I want the end result to be "ehllo world" and not "hhllo world", which is what will happen if I run 2 replace functions one after another.

I know I can do it by iterating once on the string but I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are simple, replace-one-character-with-another-single-character replacements, you can use the `translate` method:

```
>>> "hello world".translate(str.maketrans("he", "eh"))
'ehllo world'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
In [1]: s = "hello world"

In [2]: table = str.maketrans({'h': 'e', 'e': 'h'})

In [3]: s.translate(table)
Out[3]: 'ehllo world'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy.chararray.replace() method also.

```
>>> np.chararray.replace("hello world",'he','eh')
chararray('ehllo world', dtype='<U11')
```